# javascript bookmarklet gives syntax error on '()'

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am attempting to make a bookmarklet that will load up the Hacker News discussion for the page I'm on, if it exists.

Here's the code, as I have it to run in node.js's REPL:

```
// node.js stuff
require.paths.unshift('.');
var sys = require('util');
var alert = sys.puts;
var XMLHttpRequest = require("XMLHttpRequest").XMLHttpRequest;

//javascript: (function () {
    //url = 'http://api.ihackernews.com/getid?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
    url = 'http://api.ihackernews.com/getid?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://blog.asmartbear.com/self-doubt-fraud.html');
    http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("GET", url, true);

    http.onreadystatechange = (function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            alert('foo');
            var ids = eval('(' + this.responseText + ')');
            if (ids.length > 0) {
                ids.reverse();
                //window.href = ids[0];
                alert(ids[0]);
            } else {
                alert('No stories found.');
            }
        }
    });

    http.send();
//})();
```

This works as expected.  (It makes use of [a little file](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest) to simulate XMLHttpRequest in node.)

Uncommenting the function definition lines (and removing the other node-js stuff) gives me a nice little one-liner, once [packed](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/):

```
javascript:(function(){url='http://api.ihackernews.com/getid?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);http=new XMLHttpRequest();http.open("GET",url,true);http.onreadystatechange=(function(){if(this.readyState==4){alert('foo');var ids=eval('('+this.responseText+')');if(ids.length>0){window.href=ids[0]}else{alert('No stories found.')}}});http.send()})();
```

Running it, however, prompts Firefox's error console to give me the incredibly helpful message "syntax error", followed by a "()" an an error pointing to right after the second parenthesis.

I'm not using Firebug because its nightly and Firefox's nightly don't want to cooperate at the moment.

The solution to this will probably come to me soon (normally I figure it out from the process of explaining everything in this text box), but I suppose I'd appreciate any help on this.  It's really bothering me. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your response being blank (due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)) is basically executing this:

```
eval('()'); //SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

You need to add a check if there's a response at all, like this:

```
http.onreadystatechange = (function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if(this.responseText) { //was the response empty?
          var ids = eval('(' + this.responseText + ')');
          if (ids.length > 0) {
            ids.reverse();
            window.href = ids[0];
          }
        } else {
            alert('No stories found.');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Aww man I thought SO was supposed to give me one of those bars at the top when somebody beats me to an answer :(.

Comment: @Domenic: it uses occasional polling rather than waiting polling (keeping a single connection open until something happens) or the modern WebSockets PUSH way (for new browsers).  That means you may not find out for a minute or two. A pest, sometimes.

Comment: Ah, I do remember running across this before.  While your solution does prevent the error from occurring, it doesn't help my actual problem.  But that, I suppose, is for another question, and one that has been asked many times before.